# Font Manager Fails in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: fonts

The Font Manager application fails to initialize in Ubuntu 16.04.

When I run Font Manager it starts to initialize saying "Querying installed files..." but quickly hangs. An Exit needs to use the Force Quit and then I get the "Not responding" message. So there is something wrong with this version of Font Manager or its integrating with Ubuntu 16.04.

I run 64-bit version of Ubuntu.

How could that be fixed?

Comment: Try to run  `font-manager` from a terminal. Please paste any relevant lines into your question.

Comment: No, the command is `font-manager`.

Comment: I just tried the comand <font-manager> and the problem remains, it must be related to the upgrade to 16.04

Comment: But what do you see in the terminal?

Comment: INFO    :  Verified /home/fellipe/.fonts.conf
INFO    :  Font Manager is now starting

Comment: font manager opens but it hangs at the "Querying installed files..." again

Comment: Try this: `mv .fonts.conf .fonts.conf.backup` and restart font-manager.

Comment: i got those answers <mv .fonts.conf .fonts.conf.backup> and <mv .fonts.conf .fonts.conf.backup>

Comment: Are you using Kubuntu or Ubuntu?

Comment: Just to add to the answers already provided. You can simply drag fonts onto the font list in the application to install them. No need to extract first. Files, folders and archives are supported directly.

Answer (score 20):

this worked for me (ubuntu 16.04 upgrading from 15.10)

installed font manager from: http://fontmanager.github.io/

then, in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:font-manager/staging
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install font-manager
```

and downloaded font from [fonts.google.com](http://fonts.google.com) and extracted, then opened each font with right click -> font manager

confirmed 'install'

Comment: +1 works like a charm now and looks much better than the old one

Comment: What to do with the old one?

Comment: @Fleuv: If you install the PPA version, the old version will be uninstalled automatically.

Comment: i did this but also had to start the font-manager with sudo from the terminal to get new fonts installed.

Answer (score 3):

The Ubuntu and Debian archives include an ancient version of `font-manager` (0.5.7-4). One of the news in Ubuntu 16.04 was a new package for providing Chinese fonts, `fonts-noto-cjk`, and `font-manager 0.5.7-4` can't handle `fonts-noto-cjk` (see [this Debian bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/814433)).

So if you don't need Chinese fonts, an alternative workaround is to uninstall the `fonts-noto-cjk` package. (Upgrading via *ppa:font-manager/staging*, as suggested by gzb, will work without uninstalling anything.)

There is a [related Ubuntu bug](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1579536).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same experience as you. I found the solution: use PPA to install a newer version of Font Manager

https://launchpad.net/~font-manager/+archive/ubuntu/staging